# Why not doing work "for loop"?

Tags: android

When I run the program,
 then only the first input and 50,
 the multiplication of these two numbers.
 Why not working for loop? ...............when i run it code blocks.useing C programming. it works.

imagine, firstly input1=3, input2=30.i expect this output 3*30=90, 3*31=93, 3*32=96....................................3*49=147. but output shows that only 3*49=147. that is problem

......................

......................

```
package com.example.akibmahmud.namota;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    EditText et1,et2;
    private Button bt;
    ScrollView sv;
    TextView tv;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firsteditText);
        et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondeditText);
        bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        sv= (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
       bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String et11=et1.getText().toString();
               String et22=et2.getText().toString();
               if (!et11.equals("") && !et22.equals("")){
                   int input1=Integer.parseInt(et11);
                   int input2=Integer.parseInt(et22);
                   int i,k,r;
                   for (i = input1; i <=input1 ; i++) {
                       for (k =input2; k <= 50; k++) {
                           tv.setText(+i+"*"+k+"="+i*k+"/n");
                       }
                   }

               }else{
                   play();
               }
           }
       });
        setup();
    }

    private void play(){
        mp.start();
        bt.setEnabled(false);
    }
    private void loadClip(){
        try {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ok);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }catch (Throwable t){
            goBlooey(t);
        }
    }
    private void setup(){
        loadClip();
        bt.setEnabled(true);
    }
    private void goBlooey(Throwable t){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder
                .setTitle("Exception!")
                .setMessage(t.toString())
                .setPositiveButton("OK",null)
                .show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        setup();
    }
}
```

please help me.
i shall try it many times.
but it not work.

Comment: What are you expecting? And what is "not working"? If you continually `setText` in a for loop, it would change so fast you wouldn't see many of the values.

Comment: imagine, firstly input1=3, input2=30.i expect this output 3*30=90, 3*31=93, 3*32=96....................................3*49=147. but output shows that only 3*49=147. that is problem

Comment: So basically if I have an integer and I set it to 1 and then I set it to 2, you would expect it to have 1 and 2?

Comment: You will only see the last value as the UI becomes unresponsive for the duration of the `onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
for (i = input1; i <=input1 ; i++) {
                       for (k =input2; k <= 50; k++) {
                           tv.setText(+i+"*"+k+"="+i*k+"/n");
                       }
                   }
```

As `i` equals `input1` and you loop it for `i  <= input1` it won't loop. Change the initial value for `i`.

Also share your input values like what is the value of inpu1 and input2 you are trying

Comment: I'm the first to give input as any of a number. The second input to any of a number of the 50's.

Comment: sice you are continuously setting tv you are not able to see the transition. Add some kind of delay and also print the logs

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your are setting the text as fast as your CPU allows (which is a hell of a lot faster than you can see). We can fix this by adding a delay in between iterations. Like so:

```
new Thread() {
    float timeToWaitBetweenIterationsInSeconds = 1;
    public void run() {
        for (i = input1; i <=input1 ; i++) {
            for (k =input2; k <= 50; k++) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {                  
                        tv.setText(+i+"*"+k+"="+i*k+"/n");
                    }
                }
                Thread.currentThread().sleep((int) timeToWaitBetweenIterationsInSeconds*1000);
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

This snippet spawns a new thread, and for every iteration of our loop it will do the arithmetic and display the answer, then wait for the specified amount of time before continuing to the next iteration.

Also, please be aware—as @user3653796 suggests in his answer—your first loop will not work how you expect it to. I'm unsure exactly what you're attempting to do with the first loop, however if you're only trying to loop over 3 and 30 in your first loop, as stated in your question; we could simply:

```
for(int i : new int[]{3, 30})
```

Comment: I Input 1 to enter any number. If these conditions are fulfilled the first loop, the second loop can be. The number of input2 to enter the number that will be the multiplication. 1 will increase the value of the input2, it will remain until the condition of the value will increase by 1. And there will be a multiplication with input 1.All results can be seen when the conditions are not right, and the program will come out of the loop. but i see only the last output value.why??

Comment: Because you are not appending to the text, you are erasing it after every iteration and overwriting it. If you would like to append the text, I suggest trying `tv.append(String str)`, instead of `tv.setText(String str)`. I wish I could help you further with the loops, but I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.